# How can I change attribute value of Html tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this HTML code.

```js
document.getElementById("HostsBar").setAttribute("data-to", "120");
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="block-header">
            <h2>SECURITY DASHBOARD</h2>
        </div>
        <div id="burayaset">
            <!-- Widgets -->
            <div class="row clearfix">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="info-box-4">
                        <div class="icon">
                            <i class="material-icons col-blue">remove_from_queue</i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="content">
                            <div class="text">HOSTS</div>
                            <div  id="HostsBar" class="number count-to" data-from="0" data-to="125" data-speed="15" data-fresh-interval="20"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="info-box-4">
                        <div class="icon">
                            <i class="material-icons col-blue-grey">storage</i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="content">
                            <div class="text">PRODUCTS</div>
                            <div class="number count-to" data-from="0" data-to="257" data-speed="1000" data-fresh-interval="20"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="info-box-4">
                        <div class="icon">
                            <i class="material-icons col-cyan">warning</i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="content">
                            <div class="text">VULNERABILITIES</div>
                            <div class="number count-to" data-from="0" data-to="1225" data-speed="1000" data-fresh-interval="20"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I want to change count-to value with data that come from backend. How can I do that in Javascript. I tried But it not worked.

Comment: Try this `$("#HostsBar").attr("data-to", "120");`

Comment: Do you want to show the value on UI or just set it as an attribute?

Comment: I wanto show the value on UI

Comment: User `innerText` to show the value.

Comment: But its innerText value is empty, I have to change its count-to value.

Comment: How should the end output look like?

Comment: By the way it is a jquery-countto library

Answer (score 0):

its updating :

```js
alert(document.getElementById("HostsBar").getAttribute('data-to'));
document.getElementById("HostsBar").setAttribute("data-to", "120");
alert(document.getElementById("HostsBar").getAttribute('data-to'));
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="block-header">
            <h2>SECURITY DASHBOARD</h2>
        </div>
        <div id="burayaset">
            <!-- Widgets -->
            <div class="row clearfix">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="info-box-4">
                        <div class="icon">
                            <i class="material-icons col-blue">remove_from_queue</i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="content">
                            <div class="text">HOSTS</div>
                            <div  id="HostsBar" class="number count-to" data-from="0" data-to="125" data-speed="15" data-fresh-interval="20"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="info-box-4">
                        <div class="icon">
                            <i class="material-icons col-blue-grey">storage</i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="content">
                            <div class="text">PRODUCTS</div>
                            <div class="number count-to" data-from="0" data-to="257" data-speed="1000" data-fresh-interval="20"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="info-box-4">
                        <div class="icon">
                            <i class="material-icons col-cyan">warning</i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="content">
                            <div class="text">VULNERABILITIES</div>
                            <div class="number count-to" data-from="0" data-to="1225" data-speed="1000" data-fresh-interval="20"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. Its a library and it can only change by its function.

```js
$("#HostsBar").countTo({from:0, to:response});
```